# Query String Parameter used as View Name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have some code like this

```
public ActionResult BookNav(string activeId)
{
    return PartialView(activeId);
}
```

and attempt to make an Ajax call to that action. I form the callback URL using

```
@Url.Action("BookNav", "Home", new { activeId = "navHome" })
```

which yields the URL

> http://localhost:7268/Home/BookNav?activeId=navBios

I get an HTTP 500 during the callback. To simplify matters, I opened a new tab in my browser and paste in that URL. The result is:

```
The partial view 'navBios' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Home/navBios.aspx
~/Views/Home/navBios.ascx
...
```

If, however, I paste the URL without a query string parameter

> http://localhost:7268/Home/BookNav

I get the expected output.

Why is the value in my query string being used to pick the view name and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your passing a string to the `return PartialView()` which uses the overload that expects a view name (a `string`) as its parameter. You need to pass the parameter as an object

```
public ActionResult BookNav(string activeId)
{
    return PartialView((object)activeId);
}
```

Comment: D'oh! I got hung up on the notion that BookNav itself wasn't being found rather than the view. Thanks!